# How can I "deploy"/"publish" my react native app

Tags: react-native

I've made a simple react native app using the react-native init command, and I'd like to download it to my device. I'm not looking to have it on the appstore, I would just like it as an icon on my personal android**strong text** device that I can open without going through the app store. How can I accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you device is in [developper mode](http://www.greenbot.com/article/2457986/android/how-to-enable-developer-options-on-your-android-phone-or-tablet.html). Then run the command `react-native run-android` from your terminal, in your project folder.

Comment: I am asking how to publish this. So that if I had a friend who was not a developer and doesn't know how run commands, they can use that app & also not have to go through the app store, perhaps just download the file and run it. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is, you need to build an [.apk](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html) file, then send it to him.

Comment: You can try using expo

Answer (score -1):

To create a standalone app you need to use expo.

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/publishing.html

You can create a standalone app binary (an ipa or apk file) and put it in the iOS App Store and the Google Play Store.

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/index.html

#### Building Standalone Apps:

1. Install exp: `npm install -g exp`
2. Login with your Expo account: `exp login`
3. Configure app.json https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/configuration.html
4. Build: `exp build:android` or `exp build:ios`
5. Submit it to the appropriate store.